# MATLAB can't work with webcam

Tags: linux, matlab, webcam

I'm trying to connect webcam in my project, but MATLAB throws an error.

Webcamlist don't find any cam:

```
>> webcamlist

ans = 

{}
```

Two device ids:

```
>> imaqhwinfo('linuxvideo')

ans = 

       AdaptorDllName: '/home/voland/Documents/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2014b/osgenericvideointerfac...'
    AdaptorDllVersion: '4.8 (R2014b)'
          AdaptorName: 'linuxvideo'
            DeviceIDs: {[1]  [2]}
           DeviceInfo: [1x2 struct]
```

Camera is available, but don't start:

```
>> vid = videoinput('linuxvideo',1,'YUYV_640x480')

Summary of Video Input Object Using 'UVC Camera (046d:0825)'.

   Acquisition Source(s):  Camera 1 is available.

  Acquisition Parameters:  'Camera 1' is the current selected source.
                           10 frames per trigger using the selected source.
                           'YUYV_640x480' video data to be logged upon START.
                           Grabbing first of every 1 frame(s).
                           Log data to 'memory' on trigger.

      Trigger Parameters:  1 'immediate' trigger(s) on START.

                  Status:  Waiting for START.
                           0 frames acquired since starting.
                           0 frames available for GETDATA.

>> preview(vid)
Warning: Unable to reset the crop area.  Perhaps the device is in use. 
Error using imaqdevice/preview (line 176)
Could not connect to the image acquisition device.  Device may be in use.
```

dmesg:

```
[11484.585199] usb 4-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 7 using 
ehci-pci
[11484.888728] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device <unnamed> (046d:0825)
[11484.979398] input: UVC Camera (046d:0825) as  
/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb4/4-1/4-1.1/4-1.1:1.0/input/input23
```

Cameras great work on Windows 7x64 with MATLAB 2015b and on Cheese (Linux).
My system: Arch Linux x64 with MATLAB 2014b.
I have no idea about the resolve this problem. I'm hope for your help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I  think you should install support package for your cam. go to Add-on>Get Hardware Support Packages and install proper package.